# React prop validation: Multiple finite prop types?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I like to set empty array and object variables as false, I feel like it makes my code (!messier). I was wondering if there was a way to validate a finite set of prop types. Something like this:

```html
const propTypes = {
  example: PropTypes.oneOf([PropTypes.array, PropTypes.bool]).isRequired
}
```

I don't mind being told why this is a bad idea, I appreciate all the constructive comments.

Answer (score 1):

Better way is set `array` (`object`) as `null`.

```
let example = null;

propTypes = {
    example: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

if (!example) { ... }
```

Comment: Ah I never checked, I assumed null would conflict with type array. Thanks!